# XHR1 request and memory

Tags: google-chrome, memory, xmlhttprequest

When I make a series of XHR requests with Chrome using a simple script such as:

```
var q = (function DUCK(){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('POST', '/someValidPage');
    x.onload = function(){console.log("responded!");}
    x.send();
});

//Just calling XHR a bunch of times to create the bug.
q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q();
q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q(); q();
```

The browser builds up a series of 22 additional event handlers (`x.onload`) right after all the `q()` calls are made. That's expected, but the response has come down and the object is no longer in use the XHR object remains in memory until the browser's garbage collector comes by to clean it up, and it removes all the additional handlers.

I want to remove the object and events when I'm done with the object... things such as x.removeEventHandler('load') aren't showing results, and don't work with IE8 (which is also frustrating).

How do I correctly detach the events and remove the object from memory?

Comment: In IE8 you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536411(v=vs.85).aspx instead of removeEvantHandler.